# ASP.NET DropdownList autopostback and Browser Back Button

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript, html

I have an asp.net Dropdownlist with autopostback enabled. It is not populated dynamically, its values are fixed in the HTML code :

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlReportView" runat="server" autopostback="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddlReportView_SelectedIndexChanged" enableviewstate="true">
    <asp:listitem  text="Snapshot" value="SNAPSHOT"></asp:listitem>
    <asp:listitem  text="Detailled" value="DETAILLED"></asp:listitem>
    <asp:listitem  text="Review" value="REVIEW"></asp:listitem>
    <asp:listitem  text="Review Summary" value="REVIEW_SUMMARY"></asp:listitem>

</asp:dropdownlist>
```

If I select an item, it reloads the page to display a list with a different format. My problem is that when I click the back browser button, the dropdownlist's value is still the last value selected.

**Example:**

At first the list is in Snaphshot mode:
[alt text http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/3749/37948756.png](http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/3749/37948756.png)

User then clicks on Review Summary mode:
[alt text http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/545/96184426.png](http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/545/96184426.png)

The page now displays the review summary grid, all is OK:
[alt text http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/8239/13194229.png](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/8239/13194229.png)

User presses the back button, grid is displayed in snapshot mode  (which is OK), BUT the
dropdown still shows "Review Summary"!
[alt text http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/6747/22053199.png](http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/6747/22053199.png)

I tried setting the value of the select using javascript, but it does not work. Has anybody had that problem, or knows how to fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: How were you trying to change the select value using JS?

Comment: Is your dropdown in AJAX updatepanel?

Comment: javascript: 
   -wrote selected index value in an hidden textbox then set the selectedindex of the ddl on formload

Ajax:
     -No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the javascript working on this one using jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Reset drop down list
    $("#<%= dropDownList1.ClientID %> > option:first").attr("selected", "selected");        
});
```

or if the initial value should be the 'SNAPSHOT' option...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%= dropDownList1.ClientID %>").val("SNAPSHOT");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I see noone answered your question yet so here's my shot.

create a form on the page and let's name it frm1.

onload in the body make a function similar to this.

```
function checkrefresh()
    {
        if(frm1.visited.value == '' || frm1.visited.value == null) 
        {
            document.frm1.visited.value = "1";
        }
        else
        {
           document.getElementById('<%=ddlReportView.ClientId%>').selectedvalue='SNAPSHOT';
        }
    }
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: nopes... tried a similar trick but for some reason the ddl refuses to change value...

Answer (score 0):

Turn the SmartNavigation property off in the headers of your .aspxs (or alternatively in the web.configs, the property is inheritable, so it will take effect for your entire site if you put it in the root)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle browser's backbutton click

$(function () {
            jQuery(window).bind("unload", function () {
                $("#").val('0');
            });
        });