# Dropdownlist selected value does not return when navigating with browser back button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, html-select

I've got a dropdownlist. As soon as user changes its selected value, the page is reloaded.

The html looks like this:

```
<select id="period" name="MyViewModel.Period">
    <option selected="selected" value="/Home/11-2012/Index">November 2012</option>
    <option value="/Home/10-2012/Index">October 2012</option>
</select>
```

The jquery script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select#period').change(function () {
            var temp = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
            document.location.href = temp;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Everything works great, but if a user uses browser *Back* button when the original page is loaded back, it has the selected value changed. It surely confuses a user.

So, is it possible to avoid having dropdownlist value changed when navigating to a previous page through browser back button?

P.S.: this [ASP.NET DropdownList autopostback and Browser Back Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235841/asp-net-dropdownlist-autopostback-and-browser-back-button) looks like a similar problem, but it has no answer, only an idea to use java script to reassign the value. But I failed to catch how... I hope turning off caching is not the only way out. I'd better give up using dropdown list then...

[This is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025421/how-to-refresh-a-page-on-dropdownlist-value-change) my original post, which brought me to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround solving my problem.

I added a link, displaying current date, and hid the dropdownlist:

HTML:

> ```
> <select id="period_s" name="_WorkerInfoViewModel.Period">
>     <option value="url1">November 2012</option>
>     <option selected="selected" value="url2">October 2012.</option>
> </select>
> <a id="period_a" data="url2">October 2012</a>
> ```

CSS:

```
select#period_s {
display:none;
}

a#period_a {
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Then I added a jquery script toggling the dropdown list and changing the selected value in the dropdownlist. After the selected value has changed I hide the list again:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select#period_s').change(function () {
            var temp = $(this).find('option:selected').val();                
            $(this).toggle();
            document.location.href = temp;
        });
        $('a#period_a').click(function () {
            $('select#period_s').val($(this).attr('data'));
            $('select#period_s').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Until someone gives a better solution, I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> As soon as user changes its selected value, the page is reloaded.

If you could reload the content of the page using ajax then you would not be having this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no opportunity to apply ajax right now...anyway, thanks.